# parseInt ($('input#day').val())

Tags: jquery

I would like to check if this input is empty.
I need `parseInt`, but it seems to me it cause a problem to get `.length` working.

Please help, how can I solve?

My code is:

```
var myinput = parseInt ($('input#day').val());

if (myinput.length < 1){
    $('<p>Empty field</p>').appendTo('#mydiv'); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`parseInt` is not required here, just compare the length property of input value to 0.

```js
var myinput = $('input#day').val();

if (myinput.length === 0){
    $('<p>Empty field</p>').appendTo('#mydiv'); 
}

// Convert to number afterwards for that either use + unary operator or parseInt
myinput = +myinput;
```

Comment: Thank you. But I need parseInt of the value which will be added in the input field.

Comment: @N.Eli `which will be added in the input field` means?

Comment: When someone enter into input. I need to convert it to an integer the value from input ex. <input type="text"></input>